# Using euler's formula to find the number of faces

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Let (G, φ) be a 2-connected plane graph in which every vertex is incident to one
>   3-face, one 5-face, and two (opposite) 4-faces. Determine the number of faces in (G, φ).

So I know I need to figure out the number of vertices and edges to find the total number of faces using the formula. I am just stuck on how I can determine the number of vertices per face, take for example the 3-face?

Comment: this can be built as a convex polyhedron, using cardboard regular pentagons, squares, and equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark:** The way you've stated the question I'm not totally convinced it is solvable; I will solve the problem under the additional assumption that each vertex is incident with one face of length 3, one face of length 5, two (opposite) faces of length 4, **and no others** (equivalently, I'm assuming the graph is 4-regular).

Suppose $G$ has order $n$. Since each vertex is incident with one face of length 3, one face of length 5, two (opposite) faces of length 4, we have that there're $n$ incidences of vertices with faces of length 3 and 5, while there are $2n$ incidences of vertices with faces of length 4. Of course, any face of length $l$ is incident with exactly $l$ vertices, so this is to say that there're $n/3$, $n/5$, and $2n/4 = n/2$ faces of length 3, 5, and 4 respectively, or that there're $n(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5)$ = $(31/30)n$ faces in total (note that we are using our assumption that there're no other faces here).

It is elementary to see that $$\sum{l(F_i)} = 2|E(G)|$$ (Note again our use of the assumption that there're no other faces; to see the fact, simply apply the handshaking lemma to the dual graph). From this, using that $\sum{l(F_i)}$ = $4n$ (since $4(n/2) + 3(n/3) + 5(n/5) = 4n$), we have that $|E(G)|$ = $4n/2$ = $2n$ (alternatively, we may apply the handshaking lemma directly to see this, since we noted that our assumption is equivalent to $G$ being 4-regular). By Euler's formula, we may then compute $$n - 2n + (31/30)n = 2 \iff n = 60$$ (using simple algebra). Since we found above that there're exactly $(31/30)n$ faces in $G$, plugging in $n = 60$ yields 62 faces, completing the problem.

As a final remark, note that the graph we found does, in fact, exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron and matches exactly the (assumed) parameters of your question.